# При удалении readonly не вызывается клавиатура на iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Сделал костыль, чтобы браузер не вставлял пароль автоматически в поле пароль, так как современные браузеры игнорируют `autocomplete="off"` и прочие другие способы, которые можно найти. Поэтому я задаю полю аттрибут `readonly` и при фокусе удаляю его. Всё работает отлично, но вот в **iOS (Safari)** при focus'е не появляется клавиатура.

Как исправить?

```js
 $('.no_auto_complete').on('focus', function() {
  if(typeof $(this).attr('readonly') === 'undefined') {
   
  } else {
   $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" class="no_auto_complete" autocomplete="off" readonly />
```

### Не сработало:

- `autocomplete=off` к `<form>`
- `autocomplete=off` к `<form>` и к `<input>` одновременно
- `autocomplete=new-password` (в каких-то браузерах/версиях работает, в каких-то нет)

Пока единственным рабочим способом остаётся использовать fake_password.

Comment: Может быть, проблема в том, что при readonly на iOs некорректно отрабатывает событие фокуса? Вот в этом вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412990/events-stop-firing-when-focused-on-readonly-input-on-iphone у ТС-а тоже была проблема с фокусом при аттрибуте readonly. Проблема решилась по событию touchstart.

Comment: Добавьте пару скрытых полей text,password на страницу, пусть их автозаполняет. Иначе есть подозрения, что когда почините клавиатуру починится и автокомплит)

Comment: @Speller, да, действительно. touchstart это решение проблемы. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ.

Comment: @ModaL, К сожалению, вопрос с самого начала был как ответ, но модераторы преобразовали его в комментарий почему - то. Но неважно, рад, что помог!

Comment: @Speller, эхх, жаль. Система автоматически выбрала кого вознаградить, так как не дождался Вас :( Спасибо Вам огромное, очень помогли мне <3

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так же добавить `autocomplete="off"` на `<form>` - должно помочь Вам и не нужно будет писать костыли, и удалите`readonly` с input это лишнее в данном случае.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Браузер всё равно подставляет пароль, игнорируя `autocomplete="off"`. Такой способ с `autocomplete="off"` к тегу `form` описан на просторах интернета и он также ни у кого не работает.

Answer (score 3):

проблема старая и "это не косяк, это опция" (с).
попробуйте один из путей для решения:

```
<input type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>
```

или через CSS:

```
.your_class::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант работает в точности, как и у меня. Пароль не подставляется (как и нужно), но и клавиатура по-прежнему не отображается в iOS при focus'e. Второй вариант ничего не изменил совсем.

Answer (score 1):

Только на сервере придётся разобраться с `login=user&password=&password=123456`. Ну или можно лишнее поле задисейблить. И вообще, надо уже избавляться от этой любви поганить нормальное браузерное поведение.

```css
label { display: block; margin: .5em 0; }

#repass { display: none; }

@supports (-webkit-text-security: disc) {
  #repass + label { display: none; }
  #repass { display: block; }
  #repass input { -webkit-text-security: disc; }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Login: <input type="text" name="login" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <label id="repass">Password: <input type="text" name="password" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <button type="sbumit">Submit</button>
</form>
```